# Dont work bootstrap style in TagHelper ASP.NET Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

For styling, the bootstrap - pagination class is used. Before the active link are links to the previous and next page. I get links 1 2 3, not stylized buttons. I tried to style the elements through the site.css file, it did not help.

PageLinkTagHelper.cs:

```
public class PageLinkTagHelper : TagHelper
    {
        private IUrlHelperFactory urlHelperFactory;
        public PageLinkTagHelper(IUrlHelperFactory helperFactory)
        {
            urlHelperFactory = helperFactory;
        }
        [ViewContext]
        [HtmlAttributeNotBound]
        public ViewContext ViewContext { get; set; }
        public PagingInfo PageModel { get; set; }
        public string PageAction { get; set; }

        public override void Process(TagHelperContext context, TagHelperOutput output)
        {
            IUrlHelper urlHelper = urlHelperFactory.GetUrlHelper(ViewContext);
            output.TagName = "div";

            TagBuilder tag = new TagBuilder("ul");
            tag.AddCssClass("pagination");

            TagBuilder currentItem = CreateTag(PageModel.PageNumber, urlHelper);

            if (PageModel.HasPreviousPage)
            {
                TagBuilder prevItem = CreateTag(PageModel.PageNumber - 1, urlHelper);
                tag.InnerHtml.AppendHtml(prevItem);
            }

            tag.InnerHtml.AppendHtml(currentItem);

            if (PageModel.HasNextPage)
            {
                TagBuilder nextItem = CreateTag(PageModel.PageNumber + 1, urlHelper);
                tag.InnerHtml.AppendHtml(nextItem);
            }
            output.Content.AppendHtml(tag);
        }

        TagBuilder CreateTag(int pageNumber, IUrlHelper urlHelper)
        {
            TagBuilder item = new TagBuilder("li");
            TagBuilder link = new TagBuilder("a");
            if (pageNumber == this.PageModel.PageNumber)
            {
                item.AddCssClass("active");
            }
            else
            {
                link.Attributes["href"] = urlHelper.Action(PageAction, new { page = pageNumber });
            }
            link.InnerHtml.Append(pageNumber.ToString());
            item.InnerHtml.AppendHtml(link);
            return item;
        }
    }
```

This tag helper in view:

```
@addTagHelper "*, LessonProject"
...
<page-link page-model="Model.PagingInfo" page-action="List"></page-link>
```

what i have
[image]

what i want to do
[image]

Comment: Could you show the paging pictures  of your expected result and the actual result ?

Comment: Thanks, i added them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The bootstrap version is 4.x since ASP.NET Core2.2 , and the previous one is 3.x.You could add the below style in bootstrap.css

```
.pagination {
  display: inline-block;
  padding-left: 0;
  margin: 20px 0;
  border-radius: 4px;
}
.pagination > li {
  display: inline;
}
.pagination > li > a,
.pagination > li > span {
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  padding: 6px 12px;
  margin-left: -1px;
  line-height: 1.42857143;
  color: #337ab7;
  text-decoration: none;
  background-color: #fff;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
}
.pagination > li > a:hover,
.pagination > li > span:hover,
.pagination > li > a:focus,
.pagination > li > span:focus {
   z-index: 2;
   color: #23527c;
   background-color: #eeeeee;
   border-color: #ddd;
}
.pagination > li:first-child > a,
.pagination > li:first-child > span {
   margin-left: 0;
   border-top-left-radius: 4px;
   border-bottom-left-radius: 4px;
}
.pagination > li:last-child > a,
.pagination > li:last-child > span {
     border-top-right-radius: 4px;
     border-bottom-right-radius: 4px;
}
.pagination > .active > a,
.pagination > .active > span,
.pagination > .active > a:hover,
.pagination > .active > span:hover,
.pagination > .active > a:focus,
.pagination > .active > span:focus {
     z-index: 3;
     color: #fff;
     cursor: default;
     background-color: #337ab7;
     border-color: #337ab7;
}
.pagination > .disabled > span,
.pagination > .disabled > span:hover,
.pagination > .disabled > span:focus,
.pagination > .disabled > a,
.pagination > .disabled > a:hover,
.pagination > .disabled > a:focus {
      color: #777777;
      cursor: not-allowed;
      background-color: #fff;
      border-color: #ddd;
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot master! =)

Answer (score 0):

You should use chrome <kbd>F12</kbd> to compare your HTML generated by Taghelper and Bootstrap sample HTML.
If they are the same, you need to check the missed CSS styles.